# How to resize a drawable from the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-drawable, android-tablelayout

I am trying to customize the layout of a dialog. I want to have a logo in the top left corner and in the right of it, the title of the dialog. I wrote the layout below, but the editor in eclipse gives me the layout shown below, and I do not know why the logo is so wide? and the title should be to the right of it.
please let me know what I am doing wrong?

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_MainTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tr_Logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tr_Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Discovering Neigbouring Devices"
            android:/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You should really read about the layouts you are using, otherwise you won't be able to understand why ui looks the way it normally does.

Comment: @rmaik try setadjustviewbounds attribute as true on imageview

Comment: You first learn android basics and then start coding, stackoverflow is not learning site

Answer (score 2):

First of all use `android:src` instead `android:background`

So finally your **ImageView**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

**FYI** : Use **Linear Layout Instead Table Layout** .

Answer (score 1):

You have so wide logo, because you use `TableRow`.

Try to add `android:layout_weight="1"` for ImageView.

Comment: is there any way to restrict the size of it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RelativeLayout or LinearLayouts. TableLayout is not good for this.

This is an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="LOGONAME"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_end_material" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i tried  android:gravity="center_vertical" in my tablelayout to see whther it will work fine or not, but the text still in its position an does not move to be in the CenterVertica o fthe TableRow layout...any idea why that is hapenning?? thenk you

Comment: TableLayout is your problem, you can copy only the part of my code inside the "LinearLayout" incluing it. TableLayout has other purposes.

Comment: i tried your answer but i receive a warning says: the linearlyout or the relative layout are useless

Comment: That warning is saying you that you have a LinearLayout inside another LinearLayout, with nothing more, so If you want you can delete one. It is not an error, it's an alert.